# Issue getting empty character from list.files

Tags: r

I am following a tutorial online and I am having issues as when I enter in the following code

`bil.files <- list.files(path = "data/wc2-5",  pattern = "*.bil$",  full.names = TRUE)`

I am returned with a value where the characters are empty.

Any help with this please.

Thanks

Comment: Does `list.files(path = "data/wc2-5")` by itself return anything? It sounds like you might just be looking in the wrong folder on your computer.

Comment: Perfect, I re-looked at my sript and realised I was missing the folders in my workspace. Thank you